# Randomly Assigning a Bill

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let's say there are $n$ people at the restaurant table. After finishing their meal they would like to decide randomly who will pay the whole bill. Each person should have a $1/n$ probability of paying the bill. Is there a good way of arranging this lottery at the restaurant table?

Can you do this game with a fair coin? For example, $n=2$ is trivial, but if $n=3$ how should you throw the coin in order for everyone to have a $1/n$ chance?

Comment: For $n=3$, throw the coin twice. HH, I pay; HT, you pay; TH, she pays; TT, repeat the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You could get everyone to toss the coin, and whomever gets a tails does not have to pay. Then everyone who gets heads tosses again, and against those who have tails do not have to pay. Keep going till one person is left. If everyone left gets tails at some point then start again. Probably not quick, but should work...

Comment: I guess you don't have to start *all over* again if all get tails. It is enough to repeat the last toss, i.e. keep the (probably already smaller) group as it is a "fairly selected" subset. +1 for simplicity (i.e. could also be done at a bar instead of a restaurant)

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant anyway. Though technically both work.

Answer (score 2):

We shall only consider the case that $n$ is not a power of $2$.
Find the binary expansions of $\frac1n, \frac2n, \ldots, \frac{n-1}n$ (they are non-terminating eventually periodic). Now repeatedly toss a fair coin and write $0$ for heads, $1$ for tail, thus obtaining the binary expansion of a number $x$ between $0$ and $1$. You may stop as soon as there is only one $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $\frac {k-1}n\le x<\frac{k}n$. Then "player" number $k$ has "won".

---

**Example:** There are $n=5$ people, thus you compute
$$\begin{align}
\frac15&=0_2001100110011\ldots\\
\frac25&=0_2011001100110\ldots\\
\frac35&=0_2100110011001\ldots\\
\frac45&=0_2110011001100\ldots\\
\end{align} $$
My random generator just produced $HTHHHTHTH\ldots$, which translates to $0_2010001010\ldots$. In real life, I would already have stopped after three coin tosses $HTH$, because any number starting $0_2010\ldots$ must definitely be bigger than $0_2001\ldots=\frac15$ and smaller than $0_011\ldots=\frac25$. Thus player $2$ "wins". But I could not have stopped already after $HT$ because the number might still grow bigger than $\frac25$ (e.g. $0_201110$).

Comment: In principle (although with probability zero) you could wind up tossing the coin forever. So long as you reproduce the binary expansion of, say, $1/5$, you don't know whether $x$ will turn out to be bigger than $1/5$, or smaller.

Comment: @GerryMyerson One always has the problem of indefinite length and of potentially inifinite length (with probability $0$ though) if $p$ is not a power of $2$.